# Worklight Adapters - Java vs JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any drawback to having the JavaScript Worklight adapters calling Java code? Is there a performance hit, or any caveats?

The reason I ask, is that 1) I'm much more familiar with Java than JavaScript, and 2) Java is so much more powerful than JavaScript. I'm tempted to just have the adapter always call a Java class to do all the work, but I'm just concerned there might be some reasons I shouldn't.

Comment: So you want to make your application send requests over the network because you prefer writing code in Java? Yes, there can be some definite performance hits and drawbacks involved in doing that

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made this clear. What I meant was calling the Java code natively from the JavaScript adapter code - not making a network call to Java. In other words, creating my Java code in 'server/java' directory of the Worklight project, and calling it via:  
var myJavaClass = new com.mycorp.myworklight.JavaClass();

Comment: I would assume that when your java class is hosted on the WL server you would be making a network call when calling java inside the adapter. Either way when making an adapter call this would be a network call. I will look further into it, but I would expect creating new java threads on every call for every adapter procedure this may have drawbacks.

Comment: Sorry, JLRishe, you were right, I'd be introducing network calls, which would not be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Java inside of your adapters is meant as "an extension of the adapter function and not a replacement". Worklight does provide a full tutorial and even sample code of implementing java inside of your adapter which can be found here:

**Using Java in adapters presentation:**

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_08_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf

**Using Java in adapters sample:**

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/WorklightAdaptersProject.zip

As the sample mentions using java inside of your adapters is meant as an extension in cases "Where JavaScript is not enough to implement  [specific] functions, or a Java™ class [already] exists". Again this is meant as "an extension of the adapter function and not a replacement".

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking about the fact that the adapter JavaScript is not running in the same classloader as the Java code would be. I'm glad I asked the question, because that would have been a bad idea. I will avoid using Java unless necessary. Can I assume that if I use Java classes from the JRE in the adapter, that will just load the classes from the same JVM, and make no network calls?

Answer (score 3):

I can only support ravidor's statement here. Since all JavaScript in the Adapter is executed in the Java-based Rhino Javascript engine inside the Servlet and the same Servlet Context, the call of a Java Class or instantiating a Java Object does not have impacts. Running a complex code in Java might even be faster.

Nevertheless, when leaving Javascript and moving to Java you are loosing some of the architectural modularization of the adapters. All Java code is in the one Java source folder and all code has to be deployed with the full WL Console. You are loosing the loose and modular nature of the Adapters that can be maintained and deployed independent.

Also, the Worklight security framework with it's security tests and realms and all is tailored towards securing Adapter procedures.

Also, you are loosing the out-of-the box code for HTTP, SQL, etc. network communication that the Javascript adapter does automatically. If you are falling back to Java and need to call your back-end you need to code all of that network communication yourself. As well as some of the JSON transformation.

We had discussions in our projects and we ended up going with a good mix of Java for more complex data processing components and with Javascript for much of the network calls and the worklight security. In one project we even used full Groovy on the Adapter Java side and it worked fairly good. Sometimes we ran into problems with thread pooling and things like that.

Answer (score 2):

There are no drawbacks in calling Java code from the JavaScript Worklight adapters.
There are no performance hit or any other caveats.
If you feel more comfortable writing Java instead of JavaScript then you should do so.
The invocation of the adapter procedure from the client side will call the JavaScript function, from it you can call your Java code that will return to the JavaScript function and from there respond to the client with the invocation results.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there won't be any problem if you are not using JAVA for backend calls.also to make a note whenever there is a change in your java you might needs to redeploy the war again. In another case if it is JavaScript it is easy to deploy the adapters in worklight server